# not able to find likes and comments count using Facebook graph API in android

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, count

Previously(5-6 months ago approx) with the request `https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?limit=20&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&format=json` I was getting in response 20 Facebook feeds in json format with likes and comments count inside each of those 20 feeds.

But now the I'm not getting likes and comments count in the response. only that part is missing in the response.

Please tell me why now I'm not getting counts? If Facebook have changed their API, is it possible to get the count in the same request by just modifying or adding some parameters to it? And if not then what i have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution, just adding `likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)` in parameter in against "fields" worked for me.

e.g. I used `https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=story,from,story_tags,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)`

instead of `https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

Also you can add other parameters if you want; separated by a ,

Also if you want count of single post you can use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes?summary=true&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

for likes count

Or

```
    https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/comments?summary=true&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

for comment count